# MapBox directions -- getting directions own Lat and Lng

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapbox

I'm using MapBox to plot points of interest that is submitted through a user generated form built on rails. Currently the user enters a address, then the address has it's Lat and Lng calculated through a gem (geocoder). There from I pass the data from rails to javascript via the gon gem, run a forEach loop on all the points of interest, and then plot on the map using the lat and lng.

Now I want to get driving directions between the points of interest, a to b to c, etc. MapBox has a directions section, but the directions are based on the click event on the map, not stored input. Been wrestling with this for a while, and google hasn't been fruitful.

Links and advice on how to get directions between my plotted points using MapBox is hugely appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: are you usign this API? https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/directions/

Answer (score 1):

When using the Mapbox directions API you can supply your own waypoints, a semicolon separated list of coordinates.

```
http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/directions/{profile}/{waypoints}.json?access_token=<your access token>
```

Waypoints should minimaly consist of two coordinates, your start and destination coordinates. This API  should do exactly what you want. More information about on the Mapbox direction API can be found [here](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/directions/)

Comment: is that service support jsonp?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mapBox.  But notice: it is the browser that tells you your location; it's not Google Mpas, mapBox or ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize(position, accuracy) {
      alert(
        'Lat: ' + position.lat + ' - Lng' + position.lng + ' - accuracy: ' + accuracy + 'm'
      );
      ////  example for Google Maps
      // var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng);
      // ...
    }
    // request is succesful 
    function locationFound(position) {
      initialize( 
        {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude},
        position.coords.accuracy
      );
    }

    function locationNotFound() {
      alert('Not able to find your location');
    }

    function page_loaded() {
      // the page is loaded, we can send a request to search for the location of the user
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationFound, locationNotFound);
    }
</script>
<body onload="page_loaded()">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```